# Why do I not get any error when dropping a table that does not exist in sqlite?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, react-native, expo

I have a function that drops a table in a sqlite database in a expo react native project. When the table exists in the database the `console.log` statement prints `table dropped`. But if I run that same function twice in a row, Im expecting it to say `no results` because it was already dropped previously, but nothing prints on the console.

Why is that? And how do I fix this? I wish to know if sqlite transactions fail.

```
db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql(
            'DROP TABLE tableName;',
            [],
            (tx, results) => {
                if (results && results.rows && results.rows._array) {
                    /* do something with the items */
                    // results.rows._array holds all the results.
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(results.rows._array));
                    console.log('table dropped')
                }else{
                    console.log('no results')
                }
            }
        )
    });
```

Comment: DDL queries don't have results, only `SELECT` queries return results.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, its around the console.log statements, not printing to screen. If the table exists, then gets dropped, the console.log command is triggered and I see "table dropped". If the table does not exist and tries to get dropped again, why does the else statement in the if not fire?

Comment: And for clarity, no results are returned if the table drops...only the console.log('table dropped' command prints to screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to drop a table that doesn't exist causes an error. You only have a success callback, you need an error callback as well.

```
db.transaction(tx => {
  tx.executeSql(
    'DROP TABLE tableName;', [],
    (tx, results) => {
      if (results && results.rows && results.rows._array) {
        /* do something with the items */
        // results.rows._array holds all the results.
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results.rows._array));
        console.log('table dropped')
      } else {
        console.log('no results')
      }
    },
    (tx, error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }
  )
});
```